# TypeScript readline.createInterface throws exception

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create an electron app. In the main.ts I construct what I think is a fairly simple class (below) but the constructor will not run. The call to readline.createInterface(inputStream) fails. It appears that the runtime does not think the variable returned by the call to fs.createReadStream has a function called 'on' on it.

The exception is

```
Uncaught Exception:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
    at new Interface (readline.js:142:10)
    at Object.exports.createInterface (readline.js:28:10)
    at new FileMonitor (/Users/mikedice/code/electron-rm/app/FileMonitor.js:13:38)
    at App.Main.onReady (/Users/mikedice/code/electron-rm/app/Main.js:27:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at App.emit (events.js:191:7)
```

This is the block of code that generated it.

```
import readline = require("readline");
import fs = require("fs");

export class FileMonitor
{
    constructor(public filePath:string){
        if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)){
            console.log(`file does not exist at path ${filePath}`);
            return;
        }

        var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        var readInterface = readline.createInterface(inputStream);

        readInterface.on('line', (val)=>{
            // when new lines arrive we can publish an event to listeners
            console.log(val);
        });
    }
}
```

I think, the problem is that in the file /Users/mikedice/code/electron-rm/node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts the fs.createReadStream returns a ReadStream object and in the same file readline.createInterface expects a NodeJS.ReadableStream and TypeScript sees those two types as different even though the runtime expected them to be the same thing. I'm not sure what the fix is for this particular problem and in general, this type of problem. It seems like the type system of the language is inconsistent with the runtime but not sure why the runtime cannot resolve the issue when the code is executed. Any suggestions?

```
export function createReadStream(path: string | Buffer, options?: {
    flags?: string;
    encoding?: string;
    fd?: number;
    mode?: number;
    autoClose?: boolean;
    start?: number;
    end?: number;
}): ReadStream;

export function createInterface(input: NodeJS.ReadableStream,
output?: NodeJS.WritableStream, 
completer?: Completer | AsyncCompleter, 
terminal?: boolean): ReadLine;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your [`readline.createInterface()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_) options call to pass an object with the property `input.readline`. `createInterface()` expects an object with the input and/or output streams assigned.

```
readline.createInterface({input: inputStream});
```

Comment: OK got it. Your suggestion worked and also this worked:
readline.createInterface(inputStream, null, null, null);

Comment: @MikeDice If this answer solved your problem please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.